# Google Calendar API v3 DisplayName

Tags: api, calendar, google-calendar-api

I retrieve a list of events from a resource calendar.  The `DisplayName` for both the `Organizer` and `Creator` is always empty.  I tried the online [Google Calendar API Reference](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) and the sample also returns an empty `DisplayName` as well. Any ideas on how to do it?

I am using Google Calendar API v3.  Thanks.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: `organizer.displayName` and `creator.displayName` will be returned only if they are available. In my case, using the Calendar API Explorer, my public calendar will return a value on `organizer.displayName`. You can look at the description of the [Events](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource-representations) resources for more information. Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem is "only if they are available"?  What makes them available?  Is there a setting somewhere?  I am not getting the displayName even from the Google API playground...